# Generate JWT Refresh Token with go-oauth2/oauth2 library

Tags: go, oauth-2.0

I am generating Oauth2 access tokens with the go library https://github.com/go-oauth2/oauth2 (v3) . I do this with the following go pseudocode:

```
jwtParams := generates.JWTAccessGenerate{
    SignedKey:    []byte(secretKey),
    SignedMethod: jwt.SigningMethodHS512,
}
manage.Manager.MapAccessGenerate(&jwtParams)

req := oauth2.TokenGenerateRequest{
    ClientID:    clientId,
    UserID:      userId,
    RedirectURI: redirectUri,
    Code:        authCode,
}

gt := oauth2.GrantType("authorization_code")
tokenInfo, _ := manage.Manager.GenerateAccessToken(gt, &req)
```

The result I get is a JWT access token but refresh token is not.

```
access=XXXX.YYYYY                   expires=5m0s         <== JWT token - OK
refresh=YNFCZUFBWTUEXE5WJMD68W      expires=12000h0m0s   <== MY ISSUE - Not JWT
```

How do I get this library to generate a JWT refresh token?

**Update 17-Jan-2020:** After more research, I noted that many implementations don't bother with JWT representations for refresh tokens, so I may not need to as well. I would still like to know if it's feasible with this library, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Store the refresh value, use that refresh to refresh the access token in future:

```
req := oauth2.TokenGenerateRequest{
    ClientID:    clientId,
    UserID:      userId,
    RedirectURI: redirectUri,
    Code:        authCode,
}
req.Refresh = refresh
req.Scope = "owner"
rti, err := manager.RefreshAccessToken(req)
```

You can also call `manager.LoadRefreshToken(accessToken)` to load the RefreshToken from accessToken.

Comment: Our workflow is a bit a different, and we do store the refresh token, but how does your solution help me return a JWT refresh token to a client application?